# What's the Probability of Drawing Exactly One Pair?

Tags: probability, combinations

I am particularly bad at counting .... 
During a game of poker, you receive five-card hand. 
What is the probability that you have exactly one pair? 

The denominator is ${52 \choose 5}$. 
For the numerator, I put down $13{4 \choose 2} * 12{4 \choose 1} * 11{4 \choose 1} * 10{4\choose 1}$, 
which turns out to be bigger than the denominator. 
The numerator, according to the answer is $13{4 \choose 2} * 64{12 \choose 3}$. 

Why was my answer wrong? 
Suppose that you pick out any pair, that's $13{4 \choose 2}$. 
Now, you have 12 denominations left, each of which has 4 cards. 
If you pick one, that's $12{4 \choose 1}$. 
With 11 denominations left, when you pick one, that's  $11{4 \choose 1}$. 
With 10 denominations left, when you pick one, that's  $10{4 \choose 1}$. 
Clearing I am not thinking about this correctly.  Thanks!

Comment: Hint: The order of the three non-paired cards does not matter, but in your counting it does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us consider the case where we get a pair of kings. This happens in $4 \choose 2$ ways. Now, we need to choose 3 single cards. As Peter said, the order of selecting these does not matter. So we do this in $4 \choose 1$*$4 \choose 1$*$4 \choose 1$ ways. So, the total number of ways of choosing two kings is $4 \choose 2$*$4 \choose 1$*$4 \choose 1$$4 \choose 1$.

Now, there are 13 other possible pairs so the total number for each of these possible pairs is the same so we have 13*$4 \choose 2$*$4 \choose 1$*$4 \choose 1$$4 \choose 1$.

And, to calculate the total probability, we divide this by $52 \choose 5$ as you said.

The percentage seems really small but I think that it is correct?

Comment: The correct way to count the number of variations containing one pair is ${13 \choose 1}{4 \choose 2} * {4^3}{12 \choose 3}$.  Indeed, in the product, $13{4 \choose 2} * 12{4 \choose 1} * 11{4 \choose 1} * 10{4\choose 1}$, the order matters.  But if you divide this product by 3!, you will arrive at the correct total.